Is correction for multiple comparisons necessary in this instance (single variable)?
Coming here from a more analytical chemistry background, but I figured I would run my current thoughts here before committing to anything after looking around for a bit. I'm used to always using corrected post-hoc tests for ANOVAs (e.g., Tukey's HSD for pairwise compairisons), but am now faced with a methodology which has at least previously always used Fisher's LSD.
For example, I have chemical A that was measured at 5 different locations; the Fisher's LSD is being used to group the site concentrations to those significantly different from eachother. This is then repeated for each chemical that was measured. So in each case, there is only one variable (the chemical concentration) being compared amongst the different groups (k=5). (In a lot of cases you can simply look at the data and tell, so I think some would likely question the need for an ANOVA in the first place, but I think that the point is really just to make some groups that are easy to identify.)
Because there is only one variable (so each LSD test is a single variable test), is it correct to say that corrections for multiple comparisons are not required? But if, for example, we were to ask if the set of chemical concentrations (A-Z) were significantly different between the sampled sites, then we would need to correct for multiple comparisons by using something like Benjamini-Hochberg or so, correct? Unfortunately most of the information from the methodology I have doesn't explain much since it's simply done like this because it's always been done that way :P
